# Reset All My Passwords

Tags: passwords, password-management, reset

I know there are some great apps out there for keeping track of passwords (see [how-do-you-keep-track-of-all-your-passwords](https://superuser.com/questions/255/how-do-you-keep-track-of-all-your-passwords) if you aren't familiar). I'm interested in additional features for managing my passwords, particularly to reset ***all*** my passwords.

I can imagine that this feature would be pretty complicated to implement, considering:

- websites have different methods for resetting a password
- client applications most likely don't have a means to change a password except for through a graphical user interface *(as opposed to providing a command line command)*

So, I'm curious if there is a solution out there and I just haven't found it. If not, perhaps I will have to start another side project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically answered your own question, it's currently not possible considering that *websites have different methods for resetting a password*.

Comment: I try not to refuse to believe anything, because I do believe there's a solution for any problem you can think of. With that said, I hope someone out there has thought about this and perhaps started something. My intention is to bring that work into light.

Comment: As you said in the end : *perhaps you will have to start another side project*.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on why you would want to reset ALL passwords.
Netsso.com is a single sign on portal to "your" internet..i.e. you can record there your internet urls of interest to you, including credentials if needed. Then pick them up on any PC. The data is always encrypted by one "Master" password, which can be changed any time.

Comment: You might want to read this before your account gets nuked: [Limits for self-promotion in answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers)